# How to execute the Js of an Submit button in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, phantomjs

Atm I am programming with Phantomjs and I noticed that some elements of js won't work because of the render process of Phantomjs, the same for Selenium chrome driver with the headless option on. The problem is  button that have a render processes attached to them won't execute the js of the button when clicked, 
so I thought maybe I can just executed the js my self, but I am not sure 
how to execute the script of buttons , also not sure what script gets called when the button is clicked.

```html
<input id="next" name="signIn" class="rc-button rc-button-submit" value="Weiter" type="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavascriptExecutor to execute the click event like -

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.ExecuteScript("$('#next').click();", "");
```